# Remove or Replace "|" character by String method

Tags: java

I would like to remove character "|" by using `String#replaceAll()` method.
But first parameter is recognized regex meta character.

I tried `replaceAll("\|", "");` with escape character, but it cannot be compiled.

Are there any way to remove or replace "|" character by Java?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to double-escape the `|` when using `replaceAll()`, like:

```
myString.replaceAll("\\|", "");
```

This is because your string actually gets parsed *twice*, first as a literal string and then as a regular expression.  So when you start with `"\\|"` the first parse gives you a literal string of `\|`, which the regex parser then recognizes as `|`.  This can be a bit confusing until you get used to it.

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer is, don't use [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) (which replaces regexes), use [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) which simply replaces a character:

```
replace("|", "");
```

fyi, despite the method name not having "all" in it, is does in fact replace all instances of the specified character.

Answer (score 1):

Also, this does the job too:

```
String test = "Hello | Hi | Test";
System.out.println(test.replace("|", ""));
```

[String replace method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) is a useful tool here. No need to use regexes.